# Prove that the sequence $\{y_n\}$ where $y_{n+2}=\frac{y_{n+1} +2 y_{n}}{3}$ $n\geq 1$, $0<y_1<y_2$, is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Prove that the sequence $\{y_n\}$ where $y_{n+2}=\frac{y_{n+1} +2 y_{n}}{3}$ $n\geq 1$, $0<y_1<y_2$, is convergent by using subsequencial criteria, **by showing $\{y_{2n}\}$ and $\{y_{2n-1}\}$ converges to the same limit. Find the limit also**.

I can solve it by Cauchy sequence as $|y_m-y_n|\leq |y_{n}-y_{n+1}|+|y_{n+1}-y_{n+2}|\cdots +|y_{m-1}-y_m|\cdots$,
but here, we have to check convergence by using subsequencial criteria, by showing $\{y_{2n}\}$ and $\{y_{2n-1}\}$ converges to the same limit. Please help.

Comment: Hint: $y_{n+2}-y_{n+1}=\frac{-2}{3}(y_{n+1}-y_n)$.

Comment: @dxiv Not by Cauchy sequence, prove by showing {y2n} and {y2n−1} converges

Comment: That hint wasn't about Cauchy sequences, rather use it to prove monotonicity of the subsequences.

Comment: Would you please elaborate. Please write in Answer form, so that I can accept the upcoming answer.

Comment: $y_{n+1}-y_n$ changes sign at each step, and $y_{n+2}-y_n=\frac{1}{3}(y_{n+1}-y_n)\,$ P.S. This is still a hint, not a complete answer.

Comment: I understand, but a  complete answer will help me a lot.

Comment: obviously. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)** To eliminate the trivial case, first, note that if any two terms are equal $y_{n+2}=y_{n+1}$ then the recurrence gives $y_{n+1}=y_n$ and, repeating the same argument, in the end $y_2=y_1$ therefore a constant sequence. But the premise $y_1<y_2$ excludes that case, so no consecutive terms are equal.

**(2)** $\min(y_{n+1}, y_n) \le y_{n+2}=\frac{y_{n+1} +2 y_{n}}{3} \le \max(y_{n+1}, y_n)$ implies that each term is in between the previous two, so in the end all terms are within $[y_1,y_2]$ therefore the sequence is bounded.

**(3)** Writing the recurrence as $y_{n+2}-y_{n+1}=\frac{-2}{3}(y_{n+1}-y_n)\,$, with both sides being non-0 per **(1)** implies that:

$$\operatorname{sgn}(y_{n+2}-y_{n+1}) = - \operatorname{sgn}(y_{n+1}-y_{n}) = \cdots = (-1)^n \operatorname{sgn}(y_2-y_1) = (-1)^n$$

**(4)** Writing the recurrence now as $y_{n+2}-y_n=\frac{1}{3}(y_{n+1}-y_n)\,$ implies that:

$$\operatorname{sgn}(y_{n+2}-y_n) = \operatorname{sgn}(y_{n+1}-y_{n}) = (-1)^{n+1}$$

For $n=2k$ this translates to $\operatorname{sgn}(y_{2k+2}-y_{2k}) = (-1)^{2k+1} = -1\,$, so $y_{2k+2} \lt y_{2k}$ thus the sequence $(y_{2k})$ is decreasing. Similarly, the subsequence $(y_{2k+1})$ is increasing. Since both subsequences are bounded per **(2)**, both must converge.

**(5)** From **(3)** $y_{n+2}-y_{n+1}=\frac{-2}{3}(y_{n+1}-y_n)\,$ it follows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (y_{n+1}-y_n) = 0$ therefore the odd and even subsequences must converge to the same limit.

**(6)** To find the actual limit, the recurrence can be written as $3y_{k+2}=y_{k+1}+2y_k$, then summing up for $k=1\,...\,n$ and telescoping leaves in the end $3y_{n+2}+2y_{n+1}=3y_2+2y_1$. Since it's been proved already that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = L$ exists, passing to the limit gives $5 L = 3 y_2 + 2 y_1\,$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Only I am unable to understand $\min(y_{n+1}, y_n) \le y_{n+2}=\frac{y_{n+1} +2 y_{n}}{3} \le \max(y_{n+1}, y_n)$ and concltion of boundedness

Comment: @user1942348 By definition of $\min\,$ and $\max\,$, $$\min(y_{n+1}, y_n) \le y_{n+1} \le \max(y_{n+1}, y_n)$$ $$\min(y_{n+1}, y_n) \le y_n \le \max(y_{n+1}, y_n)$$ Multiply the first inequality by $\frac{1}{3}$, the second one by $\frac{2}{3}$ and add up termwise.

Answer (score 1):

You could prove that the sequence is monotonous and bounded, precisely, using induction you can prove that the sequence is monotonously increasing and is bounded from above by $y_2$. This is sufficient to prove the convergence.

Comment: The sequence is bounded, but not monotonous.

Comment: @MKBG Please help by proving that the subsequences are monotonously increasing/decreasing  and bdd above/below.

Comment: @dxiv: You are correct, thanks, just checked it as well.